# ERROR: relation "assetindexdata_id_seq" already exists on new database

Tags: database, error, back-up

I'm using PostgreSQL locally and everything is working as expected. However, when I decided to move/restore the database to the staging environment I am getting this error (even through the tables do not exist).

Has anyone experienced this before?

```
restore_pg_11.0: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "assetindexdata_id_seq" already exists
    Command was: CREATE SEQUENCE public.assetindexdata_id_seq
    AS integer
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how the database backup was created and what's being used to restore it, but using this would fix the error:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS 'public.assetindexdata_id_seq'
```

Alternatively, if you delete the database to destroy all of the associated metadata, then it shouldn't matter.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-createsequence.html

Comment: I used multiple methods with the same results, latest Craft backup but lets see if that works.

Comment: This did the trick, there was a previous install on the database that was dropped but the sequence was still there. Thanks Brad!